# How do you address a policeman on duty?

Tags: forms-of-address

How do you address a policeman while he is on duty (e.g., when you are asked to stop at a checkpoint)? The word "policeman" itself seems quite unusual to me, and some sources suggest "officer". Is that correct?

Is there any difference in use if the policeman is a woman: should you use a different word?

Also, is "cop" a wrong word to use in this context (i.e., potentially offensive or derogatory)?

Comment: @StoneyB Good point: I will update the question to... address your comment.

Comment: Marco Leogrande, "if the policeman is a woman", they would not be a policeman http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/policeman?q=policeman They would be a policewoman http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/policewoman

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The official term is *police officer*, so *officer* seems to be the best term, neutral and respectful. It also seems valid regardless of their rank, gender, etc.

> Excuse me *officer*, may I ask why my car was stopped?
>   Excuse me *officer*, I just wanted to tell you that you have a headlight out.

Answers to [this question at ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59098/what-is-the-correct-form-of-address-for-a-police-officer) also suggest *sir* and *ma'am* (not *madam*, thanks @tchrist) as good alternative.
Also, UK English has another word, *constable*, which is a bit too official, but quite acceptable.

**And don't try slang words!** In some countries, it may lead you straight to jail.

P.S. In some countries, a police officer holds a highly respected position, and rank does matter. So if you are traveling **and** you can read [insignia of ranks](http://www.google.com/search?q=police+ranks+insignia&tbm=isch) **and** you know what you are doing, you may call them by rank to show your highest respect:

> Excuse me *lieutenant*, ...

Comment: Don’t say  *madam*, say *maam*.  Honest.  You don’t want to risk her thinking you are calling her the matron of a flock of strumpets.

Comment: Also, even if you do understand the insignia of ranks, be careful. It's more insulting to guess and get it wrong than it is to just refer to the police officer by a more general term. If the police officer holds rank, it's likely that they would introduce themselves by it at the start of the conversation anyway ("Excuse me. My name is Detective Inspector Wiggins. Do you mind if I ask you a few questions?")

Comment: @Matt, correct. OTOH, if you really, really know what you are doing, calling an officer by a _higher_ rank (than they are) may appear helpful. In any case, out of scope of this site. :)

Comment: *Constable* designates a low-ranking policeman: the equivalent of a private in the Army.

Comment: StoneyB, that's a good point. The word *constable* is for a particular rank in British police services. It is therefore inappropriate to use for police officers in general or, police officers whose rank is unknown.

Comment: bytebuster, the word *constable* is for a particular rank in British police services; short for police constable (abbreviation **PC**) http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/police-constable?topic=people-who-work-for-the-police-service It is not a way to address any police officers.

Answer (score 10):

Definitely go with *officer*, for example in the sentence:

> **Excuse me officer**, could you please point me in the direction of the nearest police station?

You can also use the term "police" when referring to non-specific officers in the general sense, for example:

> Stop! Help! **Police**! That man stole my wallet!

There are a great many different slang words for the police, but you should avoid most of them as most of them are offensive and may get you into trouble.

Note that police officers are people too, so if you forget you can simply ask your question as you would to any other member of the public:

> **Excuse me**, I was wondering if you could help me unlock my bicycle; the lock is stuck.

Comment: This is the best answer. Your last example makes an important point. There is no particular way of addressing a police officer, in the English language. That's why they can be addressed as any other member of the public, with general wording like **excuse me**, as long as it is polite.

Answer (score 4):

The term *"police officer"* is the best term to use as it is gender-neutral and is not considered derogatory. In some countries it's also perfectly alright to use the officer's rank (such as *Sergeant* or *Constable*), *"police officer"* is neutral.

Whilst the terms *"police man"* and *"police woman"* are technically correct, it is safer to just use the neutral term.

You may also hear other (slang) terms being used to reference members of the police force, but most of these can be considered derogatory and should generally be avoided. For example:

- *Cop*  - Whilst this term is commonly used (and is even the title of an American TV show), it should generally be avoided to ensure that you don't cause offense.
- *Pig*  - Completely derogatory and should not be used.
- *Fuzz*  - As above.
- *Bobby* - Used in British English, and the British Police don't seem to mind - but you should avoid the term if you're not a native speaker and not comfortable in its appropriate usage.

Comment: But be sure not to accidentally call them "ossifer"

Comment: In the UK, whilst the police are often called "Bobbies" - for example "Bobbies on the Beat" meaning policemen on the streets, I'd generally call any particular member of the police "officer" rather than "Bobby".

Comment: If you accidentally say "ssifer", that's nothing that a little breathalyzer test won't clear up.

Comment: You missed 'Filth'.  Although this is generally derogatory, our local Police Commissioner fancies himself a muso and has created a band called 'The Filth'. Jokes about being locked up for murdering the music abound.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't usually address an officer as "cop" anyway, as in "excuse me cop, where's the ..." It's not used as a form of address like "officer" (or even "pig").

Comment: "Police officer" is the *occupational term*. It is not, and should not be used as, a *term of address*. For that, stick to just "officer". (It's the same problem with "cop", "fuzz", and "bobby": they're fine as informal occupational terms, as long as you're not within earshot of someone who holds said occupation; but they do not work, grammatically, as a term of address.)

Comment: Addressing an officer as "Ossifer" instead of "Officer" would be considered "cheeky" in the UK.  Usually not done to an officer's face.

Answer (score 3):

"Cop" is not derogatory, but it is also not a title. So "Officer, there are a lot of cops here," NOT "Cop, there are a lot of officers here."

If people introduce themselves with a title, like detective, lieutenant, or sergeant, use that. If they do not provide a title or you didn't catch it, "officer" is always a good fallback. It is probably preferable to sir or ma'am and can be used for both genders.